# Webpack getting started with Laravel. How to setup workflow?

Tags: laravel-5, webpack, laravel-elixir

I am currently using Webpack with Laravel to manage dependencies on a new project. My current workflow looks like this:

```
npm install whatever-package

require('whatever-package'); (in frontend.js)
```

GulpFile.JS >

```
elixir(mix => {
    //the core scss file. contains bootstrap and vendor stuff.
    mix.sass('frontend.scss')
       .webpack('frontend.js');
}
```

run `gulp`

Frontend.js is then included in my PHP template. This would work great for a single page application, but if I want to have one javascript file, and multiple web pages what technique should I be using to pull in javascript for other pages?

Should I have multiple JS files all webpacked with Elixir? Or what is the next step to require in the right files?

i.e. does Webpack support a single entry point where I can start to load other scripts via data attributes? I've used this technique with requireJS previously, and just trying to wrap my head around the best way to do this with Webpack.

Comment: What I usually do with Laravel is I make a separate JS file for each route. Then when I load the page I check if a JS file with the routes name exists, include it. If I have script that needs to be on multiple pages I extract it to a module and then add the module to each page.

Comment: @TheFallen - you check server side for the presence of the file, or client side? Or a combination? i.e does your view have require('route.js'); somewhere inline?

Comment: I check from the server side if file with name of the current route exists and then add it to the header if it does.